# angular $timeout after a successfull function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am calling a Cordova plugin from angular where i must put a certain delay between my calls to give the native hardware time to initialize or perform the task.

The time should be given even when just after they have return a success response.

The problem is everything i sent at once no matter what i try

// initial code removed as it hurts @Fizzix eyes.

Now the is perfect but not the timing...

```
 simplePrint: function(text, startEnterLines, endEnterLines) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                printer.open().then(
                    $timeout(printer.init(), 500)
                ).then(
                    $timeout(printer.writeEnterLine(startEnterLines), 1000)
                ).then(
                    $timeout(printer.printText(text), 1200)
                ).then(
                    $timeout(printer.writeEnterLine(endEnterLines), 1300)
                ).then(
                    deferred.resolve($timeout(printer.closePrinter(), 3000))
                );
                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

Comment: I am sorry.. I have removed the offending code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example how to use promise chains would be,

```
$q.when(true).then(function(value) {
    // Do work, return promise
}).then(function(value) {        
    // Do work, return promise
}).then(function(value) {
    // Do work, return promise
}).then(function(value) {        
    // Do work, return promise
}, function(value) {        
    // Do work
});
```

You should read more about chaining promises without breaking the sequence.
.
Please find some good examples.

- [Javascript Promise chains - a useful document with some examples](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/)
- [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)
- [Simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsengel/0ryvkvph/)

  Hope these details help.

Comment: thanks i think i should read the docs.. i was able to get the sequence right by copying your example but the timing still dont work..

Comment: Happy to hear. The timing should be enabled by putting code inside $timeout at each level I assume.

Comment: let me update the question, while finding something in the doc